# Java case-insensitive map with null key

Tags: java, collections, null, case-insensitive

Is there a Map implementation in Java that will use **case-insensitive** String matching for the key, **but also supports the null key**?
I know that

```
new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

supports case-insensitive matching of String keys, but it doesn't support the null key.

Comment: If you use your own class for the key it is up to you to implement `equals` and `hashCode` so that they work case insensitive.

Comment: Perhaps use `Objects.toString(key)` when inserting in the map. That will map the key to the string `null`.

Comment: Look at the implementation where case sensitivity is taken.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted...

Comment: Related: [null-safe mapping Comparator using default implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28499846). [How to handle nulls when using Java collection sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3671826). [What to do with null fields in compare()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128042) [comparator with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2401606)

Answer (score 31):

If you're on Java 8, the following will create a null-compatible, case-insensitive `TreeMap`:

```
Comparator<String> cmp = Comparator.nullsFirst(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(cmp);
```

No external libraries needed.

Comment: Worth noting that by using a TreeMap, `get`, `put` and `remove` operations will be O(log(n))

Answer (score 8):

You can use [CaseInsensitiveMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CaseInsensitiveMap.html) for this. This will fulfill your requirement.
It is case-insensitive as well as supports null keys.

From the doc

> > A case-insensitive Map. Before keys are added to the map or compared to other existing keys, they are converted to all lowercase in a
> >     locale-independent fashion by using information from the Unicode data
> >     file.
>
> Null keys are supported.
>
> The keySet() method returns all lowercase keys, or nulls.

Answer (score 5):

If you would prefer not using external libraries, you could make your own wrapper for `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` that sorts `null`s in a predictable way:

```
 NavigableMap<String,String> m = new TreeMap(
    new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            if (s1 == null && s2 == null) return 0;
            if (s1 != null && s2 != null) {
                return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(s1, s2);
            }
            return s1 == null ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
 );
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/lY0zc2)